# C reading lines and spaces from a file using dynamic allocation

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am attempting to read a matrix from a file by using reverse engineering process. The first part of what I am attempting to do is to create a file using malloc or calloc. I used malloc since the user is prompted the number of rows or columns to enter. I also made the final matrix to be printed out on the screen and a user-defined file-name.

The issue that I am having right now is that I am able to fetch the file name on the second part, however once the file name is found, the program freezes and ceases to perform the next operation.

Here is my code below:

```
//preprocessors

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

//macros

#define STRING_MAX 50

//function prototypes

void printDiagonal (double ** m, int r, int c);

int main (int argc, char * argv [ ])
{
FILE * ptrIn;
FILE * ptrOut;

char inFileName [STRING_MAX];
char outFileName [STRING_MAX];

int row;
int col;

int r;
int c_temp;
int c;

char spaces;
char lines;

int i, j, k;

int ctrSpaces = 0;
int ctrLines = 0;
int ctrH = 0;
int ctrV = 0;

double matrixVals;
double ** matrixIn;
double ** matrixOut;

//get a file name first

printf ("\nEnter a file name >> ");
scanf ("%s", inFileName);

//open the file

ptrIn = fopen (inFileName, "w");

//get matrix dimensions

printf ("\nEnter the row and column sizes >> ");
scanf ("%d", &row);
scanf ("%d", &col);
printf ("\nRows >> %d\nCols >> %d\n\n", row, col);

matrixIn = (double **) malloc (row * sizeof (double *));
if (matrixIn == NULL)
{
    printf ("\nSORRY, NOT ENOUGH MEMORY!\n\n");
    exit (0);
}
for (i = 0; i < row; i ++ )
{
    matrixIn [i] = (double *) malloc (col * sizeof (double));
    if (matrixIn [i] == NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nSORRY, NOT ENOUGH MEMORY!\n\n");
        exit (0);
    }
}

//input the values into the matrix

printf ("\nEnter the values into the matrix >> \n\n");

for (i = 0; i < row; i ++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j ++)
    {
        printf ("\n\nEnter [%d][%d] of [%d][%d] >> ", (i + 1), (j + 1), row, col);
        scanf ("%lf", &matrixIn [i] [j]);
    }
}

//print out the matrix

printf ("\nElements in the matrix >> \n\n");
for (i = 0; i < row; i ++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j ++)
    {
        printf ("%.3lf\t", matrixIn [i][j]);
        fprintf (ptrIn, "%.3lf\t", matrixIn [i][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    fprintf (ptrIn, "\n");
}
printf ("\n");
fprintf (ptrIn, "\n");

for (i = 0; i < row; i ++)
{
    free (matrixIn [i]);
}
free (matrixIn);

fclose (ptrIn);

printf ("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

/**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/

//now retrieve the file by first getting user input for file name and check that the file exists

FILE_NAME:

printf ("\nEnter the name of file to access >> ");
scanf ("%s", outFileName);
printf ("\nThe name of the file is >> %s\n\n", outFileName);

//now open the file

ptrOut = fopen (outFileName, "r");

//check that the file exists

if (ptrOut == NULL)
{
    printf ("\nSORRY, THE FILE DOES NOT EXIST. PLEASE ENTER A VALID FILE NAME.\n\n");
    goto FILE_NAME;
}

//get the number of rows and columns

for (lines = fgetc (ptrOut); lines != EOF; lines == fgetc (ptrOut))
{
    if (lines == '\t' || lines == ' ')
    {
        ctrLines ++;
        if (lines == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

c_temp = ctrLines;

for (spaces = fgetc (ptrOut); spaces != EOF; spaces = fgetc(ptrOut))
{
    if (spaces == '\n')
    {
        ctrSpaces ++;
        if (spaces == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

r = ctrSpaces;

//total number of rows is:

c = c_temp / r;

printf ("\nNumber of rows >> %d\n\nNumber of columns >> %d\n\n", r, c);

matrixOut = (double **) malloc (r * sizeof (double *));
if (matrixOut == NULL)
{
    printf ("\nSorry, not enough memory!\n\n");
    exit (0);
}

for (i = 0; i < r; i ++)
{
    matrixOut [i] = (double *) malloc (c * sizeof (double));
    if (matrixOut [i] == NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nSorry, not enough memory!\n\n");
        exit (0);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < r; i ++)
{
    free (matrixOut [i]);
}
free(matrixOut);

fclose (ptrOut);

//reopen the file and get the information from the file

ptrOut = fopen (outFileName, "r");

matrixOut = (double **) malloc (c * sizeof (double *));

for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    matrixOut [i] = (double *) malloc (c * sizeof (double));
}

printf ("\nMatrix from File %s of dimensions %d X %d >>\n\n", outFileName, r, c);

for (i = 0; i < r; i ++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < c; j ++)
    {
        fscanf (ptrOut, "%lf", &matrixVals);
        matrixOut [i] [j] = matrixVals;
        printf ("%.3lf\t", matrixOut [i] [j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
printf ("\n");

for (i = 0; i < r; i ++)
{
    free (matrixOut [i]);
}
free(matrixOut);

fclose (ptrOut);

return (0);
}
```

This is my output: 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqM2tvkVzTumh58mcliiAUKD9Uu7Ew.

For clarification of my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Aside: `char spaces` ==> `int spaces` please look at the return type of the functions you use. Otherwise: a wall of code. `char lines` is another culprit.

Comment: Mystified by `ctrSpaces ++; if (ctrSpaces == EOF) { ... )`

Comment: @WeatherVane: `ctrSpaces ++` is used to count spaces in the file being read.

Comment: and when would it equal EOF ? when it happens to equal EOF (usually -1)

Comment: @GradyPlayer: Sorry that was a typo. I meant `spaces`, not `ctrSpaces.`

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output a long string of warning messages.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers will use different parameters to obtain the same effect.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to output your error message and the text of why the OS thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `printf ("\nSorry, not enough memory!\n\n");
        exit (0);`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error is from a C library function, also output the text reason the OS thinks the error occurred. (function: `perror()` handles this very nicely.)  in general, a returned value of 0 indicates success,  Suggest using: `EXIT_FAILURE`

Comment: Once the code block beginning with: `
for (lines = fgetc (ptrOut); lines != EOF; lines == fgetc (ptrOut))` exits, then the 'file pointer' will be at the end of the file and EOF will be active.  So the code block beginning with: `for (spaces = fgetc (ptrOut); spaces != EOF; spaces = fgetc(ptrOut))` will never be executed

Comment: when calling: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input/format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]', always include a MAX FIELD WIDTH modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and resulting undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `char spaces;
char lines;`  the returned value from: `fgetc()` is an integer and EOF is an integer. so those statements should be: `int spaces;
int lines;

Comment: regarding: `if (spaces == '\n')
    {
        ctrSpaces ++;
        if (spaces == EOF)`  there is no way that 'spaces' can be equal to ' ' AND equal to EOF at the same time

Comment: the code sequence starting with: `matrixOut = ,,, malloc( ... )` and ending with: `free(matrixOut);`  does absolutely nothing and can be completely eliminated

Comment: regarding: `fclose (ptrOut);

//reopen the file and get the information from the file

ptrOut = fopen (outFileName, "r");`  the code could simply say: `rewind( ptrOut );`

Comment: regarding: `goto FILE_NAME;`  The `goto()` statement is rarely ever a good idea.  Strongly suggest implementing a loop to get a usable file name.  (and you might want to learn about `stat()`

Comment: @user3629249: Thanks. I was able to solve the problem. Just a matter of reopening the file after the first iteration of countlng lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did thanks to user3629249. I just had to separate the two operations of reading line number and reading row numbers. For row numbers, I had to subtract 1 from the total row count since it adds in an extra `\0`after `EOL`.

Here is my final code (along with the functions that I did not mention originally to print out the major and "minor" diagonals of a square matrix.

```
 //preprocessors

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

//macros

#define STRING_MAX 50

//function prototypes

void printMajorDiagonal (double ** m, int r, int c);
void printMinorDiagonal (double ** m, int r, int c);

int main (int argc, char * argv [ ])
{
FILE * ptrIn;
FILE * ptrOut;

char inFileName [STRING_MAX];
char outFileName [STRING_MAX];

int row;
int col;

int r;
int c_temp;
int c;

char spaces;
char lines;
char ch;

int i, j, k;

int ctrSpaces = 0;
int ctrLines = 0;
int ctrH = 0;
int ctrV = 0;
int charCount = 0;
int lineCount = 0;

double matrixVals;
double ** matrixIn;
double ** matrixOut;

//get a file name first

printf ("\nEnter a file name >> ");
scanf ("%s", inFileName);

//open the file

ptrIn = fopen (inFileName, "w");

//get matrix dimensions

printf ("\nEnter the row and column sizes >> ");
scanf ("%d", &row);
scanf ("%d", &col);
printf ("\nRows >> %d\nCols >> %d\n\n", row, col);

matrixIn = (double **) malloc (row * sizeof (double *));
if (matrixIn == NULL)
{
    printf ("\nSORRY, NOT ENOUGH MEMORY!\n\n");
    exit (0);
}
for (i = 0; i < row; i ++ )
{
    matrixIn [i] = (double *) malloc (col * sizeof (double));
    if (matrixIn [i] == NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nSORRY, NOT ENOUGH MEMORY!\n\n");
        exit (0);
    }
}

//input the values into the matrix

printf ("\nEnter the values into the matrix >> \n\n");

for (i = 0; i < row; i ++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j ++)
    {
        printf ("\n\nEnter [%d][%d] of [%d][%d] >> ", (i + 1), (j + 1), row, col);
        scanf ("%lf", &matrixIn [i] [j]);
    }
}

//print out the matrix

printf ("\nElements in the matrix >> \n\n");
for (i = 0; i < row; i ++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j ++)
    {
        printf ("%.3lf\t", matrixIn [i][j]);
        fprintf (ptrIn, "%.3lf\t", matrixIn [i][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    fprintf (ptrIn, "\n");
}
printf ("\n");
fprintf (ptrIn, "\n");

for (i = 0; i < row; i ++)
{
    free (matrixIn [i]);
}
free (matrixIn);

fclose (ptrIn);

printf ("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

/**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/

//now retrieve the file by first getting user input for file name and check that the file exists

FILE_CHECK:

printf ("\nEnter the name of file to access >> " );
scanf ("%s", outFileName);
printf ("\nThe name of the file is >> %s\n\n", outFileName);

//now open the file

ptrOut = fopen (outFileName, "r");
if (ptrOut == NULL)
{
    printf ("Sorry, the file does not exist. Re-enter another file-name.\n\n");
    goto FILE_CHECK;
}

//read lines first - total number of lines == total number of rows

for (lines = getc (ptrOut); lines != EOF; lines = getc (ptrOut))
{
    if (lines == '\n')
    {
        ctrLines ++ ;
    }
}

r = ctrLines - 1;

matrixOut = (double **) malloc (r * sizeof (double *));
if (matrixOut == NULL)
{
    printf ("\nSorry, not enough memory!\n\n");
    exit (0);
}

free (matrixOut);

printf ("\nRows >> %d\n\n", r);

/*******************************************************************************************************************************************/

//open the file again to count columns

ptrOut = fopen (outFileName, "r");

for (spaces = getc (ptrOut); spaces != EOF; spaces = getc (ptrOut))
{
    if (spaces == ' ' || spaces == '\t' || spaces == '\b')
    {
        ctrSpaces ++ ;
    }
}

c_temp = ctrSpaces;

c = c_temp / r;

printf ("\nCols >> %d\n\n", c);

for (i = 0; i < r; i ++)
{
    matrixOut [i] = (double *) malloc (c * sizeof (double));
    if (matrixOut [i] == NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nSorry, not enough memory!\n\n");
        exit (0);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < r; i ++ )
{
    free (matrixOut [i]);
}
fclose (ptrOut);

//reopen the file again to read the matrix elements line by line

ptrOut = fopen (outFileName, "r");

matrixOut = (double **) malloc (r * sizeof (double *));

for (i = 0; i < r; i ++)
{
    matrixOut [i] = (double *) malloc (c * sizeof (double));
}

//print out the matrix here

printf ("\nThe matrix in the file %s of size %d x %d.\n\n", outFileName, r, c);

for (i = 0; i < r; i ++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        fscanf (ptrOut, "%lf", &matrixVals);
        matrixOut [i] [j] = matrixVals;
        printf ("%.3lf\t", matrixOut [i] [j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
printf ("\n");

printMajorDiagonal (matrixOut, r, c);
printMinorDiagonal (matrixOut, r, c);

for (i = 0; i < r; i ++)
{
    free (matrixOut [i]);
}
free (matrixOut);

fclose (ptrOut);

return (0);
}

//function definitions

void printMajorDiagonal (double ** m, int r, int c)
{
//prints out the major diagonal
int i, j;
if (r == c)
{
    printf ("\nMajor Diagonal >> \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r; i ++)
    {
        printf ("%.3lf\t", m [i] [i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
else if (r != c)
{
    printf ("\nThe major diagonal cannot be printed since the given matrix is not a square matrix.\n\n");
}
}

void printMinorDiagonal (double ** m, int r, int c)
{
//prints out the opposite "minor" diagonal
int i, j;
if (r == c)
{
    printf ("\nMinor Diagonal >> \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r; i ++)
    {
        printf ("%.3lf\t", m [r - i - 1] [i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
else if (r != c)
{
    printf ("\nThe major diagonal cannot be printed since the given matrix is not a square matrix.\n\n");
}
}
```

Once again, thanks everyone involved in helping me out. My mistake was failing to re-initiate the file after the first iteration of line counting.

Much appreciated `StackOverFlow!`